# How can I use HasPropertyValueSelector in my project?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, dotnetrdf

I am new to dotNetRDF and I have a problem maybe namespaces or framework.

Although I'm adding namespaces to the my project, the following code doesn't work.

System given an error that namespace not found.

```
HasPropertyValueSelector sel = new HasPropertyValueSelector(rdfType, carnivore);
```

All codes are below;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using VDS.RDF;
using VDS.RDF.Parsing;
using VDS.RDF.Query;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Graph g = new Graph();
            UriLoader.Load(g, new Uri("http://example.org/animals"));
            IUriNode rdfType = g.CreateUriNode("rdf:type");
            IUriNode carnivore = g.CreateUriNode("ex:Carnivore");

           ***HasPropertyValueSelector sel = new HasPropertyValueSelector(rdfType, carnivore);***
           IEnumerable<Triple> carnivores = g.GetTriples(sel);

            Graph ourlist = new Graph();
            ourlist.NamespaceMap.AddNamespace("ex", new Uri("http://example.org/"));

            IUriNode rdfType2 = ourlist.CreateUriNode("rdf:type");
            IUriNode animal = ourlist.CreateUriNode("ex:Animal");

            foreach (Triple t in carnivores)
            {

               ourlist.Assert(new Triple(Tools.CopyNode(t.Subject, ourlist), rdfType2, animal));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your life as an engineer will be much easier if you avoid fluffy statements like "System doesn't recognize this statement." Nobody knows that that means. Use an objective statement such as "This line of code raises the compilation error "Type or namespace not found; are you missing an assembly reference?" or "The program throws an exception when it reaches this line. The exception is 'Object reference not found.'" That sort of thing. Just the technical specifics, please. Welcome to SO BTW.

Comment: You are right. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: *NB* - You also need to add details like which version of the library you are using.  This looks like a very old API that has long since been deprecated/removed from the library.  Also this is not a valid C# code, did you not cut and past the entire thing?  You appear to be missing both the `namespace YourNamespace` and `class YourClass` definitions in the code

Answer (score 0):

The one step that you are missing is to define your namespaces before you create URI nodes that use them. This is done with the NamespaceMapper which is found on the IGraph interface. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Using-The-Namespace-Mapper), but a simple example would be:

```cs
IGraph g = new Graph();

//Define the Namespaces we want to use
g.NamespaceMap.AddNamespace("rdf", new Uri("http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"));
g.NamespaceMap.AddNamespace("ex", new Uri("http://example.org/"));

//Define the same Triple as the previous example
UriNode rdfType = g.CreateUriNode("rdf:type");
UriNode exCarnivore = g.CreateUriNode("ex:Carnivore");

var carnivores = g.GetTriplesWithPredicateObject(rdfType, exCarnivore);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I view document your given and understand it and define namespaces but System still  given an error that namespace not found.                                
     HasPropertyValueSelector sel = new HasPropertyValueSelector(rdfType, carnivore);

Comment: I don't recognize `HasPropertyValueSelector` from the dotNetRDF codebase, so I assume that this is either your own code or another library - in which case I can't really help explain why that code doesn't work. However, dotNetRDF already has a method `IGraph.GetTriplesWithPredicateObject` that does what you want. I've updated the example in my answer to show how to get the list of triples that match.

Comment: @Kal I think this is from an old and deprecated API from very early versions

Comment: @BünyaminAliYılmaz As @Kal's answer is trying to show there is no need to use `HasPropertyValueSelector` at all, just use the `GetTriplesWithPredicateObject()` method instead.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and advice. I have studied DotNetRdf library since last week. Now I better undestand this library. GetTriplesWithPredicateObject method is very usefull for selecting any nodes or triples. Thanks again.